# why tidyverse group_by behave unexpected after R update

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

It used to work fine and then I updated R!
After the updates, the group_by function considers every row as a group. In the following example dataset `dtt` if I filter the dataset to only one group and run the code, it works as expected. However if run the same code for all groups, it does not work as expected.

Here are working and not working codes and below is data.

#Filter `dtt` to only one group (x,y) and run the code then it works as expected as below

```
dtt_xy<-dtt%>%
        filter(x==-121 & y == 65)
dtt_xy

dtt_output <- dtt_xy%>%
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Date) != 1)), .add = TRUE)
dtt_output #Expected output
```

#Now if run the same code for the whole dataset i.e., `dtt` it does not work

```
dtt_output <- dtt%>%
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Date) != 1)), .add = TRUE)
dtt_output #Not expected output . expectation is 35 groups
```

Sample Data

```
dtt<-structure(list(x = c(-121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, 
-120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, 
-121, -120, -121, -121, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, 
-120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, 
-121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, 
-120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, 
-121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, 
-120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, 
-121, -120, -120, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, 
-120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, 
-121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, 
-120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, 
-121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, 
-120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120, -121, -120
), y = c(65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 
65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 
63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 
63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 
63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 
65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 63, 63, 65, 63, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 
63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 63, 63, 65, 
65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 
65, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 
63, 65, 65, 63, 63, 65, 65, 63, 63), Date = structure(c(5123, 
5123, 5123, 5123, 5124, 5124, 5124, 5124, 5125, 5125, 5125, 5125, 
5126, 5126, 5126, 5126, 5127, 5127, 5127, 5127, 5128, 5128, 5177, 
5177, 5177, 5177, 5178, 5178, 5178, 5178, 5179, 5179, 5179, 5179, 
5180, 5180, 5180, 5180, 5181, 5181, 5181, 5181, 5200, 5200, 5200, 
5200, 5201, 5201, 5201, 5201, 5202, 5202, 5202, 5202, 5203, 5203, 
5203, 5203, 5204, 5204, 5204, 5204, 5205, 5205, 5205, 5205, 5206, 
5206, 5206, 5206, 5238, 5238, 5239, 5239, 5240, 5240, 5273, 5273, 
5273, 5273, 5274, 5274, 5274, 5274, 5319, 5319, 5320, 5325, 5326, 
5326, 5327, 5327, 5327, 5327, 5328, 5328, 5328, 5328, 5329, 5329, 
5329, 5329, 5330, 5330, 5330, 5330, 5331, 5331, 5344, 5344, 5345, 
5345, 5381, 5381, 5382, 5382, 5383, 5383, 5383, 5383, 5384, 5384, 
5384, 5384, 5401, 5401, 5402, 5402, 5402, 5402, 5403, 5403, 5403, 
5403, 5404, 5404, 5404, 5404, 5405, 5405, 5405, 5405, 5406, 5406, 
5406, 5406, 5407, 5407, 5407, 5407), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-150L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

## Session Info

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.5     purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.4.0     tidyr_1.1.3    
[7] tibble_3.1.0    ggplot2_3.3.3   tidyverse_1.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.5.1     compiler_4.0.4   dbplyr_2.1.0     tools_4.0.4     
 [7] jsonlite_1.7.2   lubridate_1.7.10 lifecycle_1.0.0  gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_0.4.10    
[13] reprex_1.0.0     cli_2.3.1        rstudioapi_0.13  DBI_1.1.1        haven_2.3.1      withr_2.4.1     
[19] xml2_1.3.2       httr_1.4.2       fs_1.5.0         generics_0.1.0   vctrs_0.3.6      hms_1.0.0       
[25] grid_4.0.4       tidyselect_1.1.0 glue_1.4.2       R6_2.5.0         fansi_0.4.2      readxl_1.3.1    
[31] modelr_0.1.8     magrittr_2.0.1   backports_1.2.1  scales_1.1.1     ellipsis_0.3.1   rvest_1.0.0     
[37] assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_2.0-0 utf8_1.2.1       stringi_1.5.3    munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.7.5     
[43] crayon_1.4.1
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: See the modified question that indicates my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this has been one of the recent change in `dplyr` when you do a nested `group_by`. An issue was created earlier for [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5705) but it was closed and it doesn't seem that this behaviour is going to change.

Solution is to use `mutate` to create the new column and then use it in `group_by`.

```
library(dplyr)

dtt%>%
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Date) != 1))) %>%
  group_by(grp, .add = TRUE)

# A tibble: 150 x 4
# Groups:   x, y, grp [35]
#       x     y Date         grp
#   <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <int>
# 1  -121    65 1984-01-11     1
# 2  -120    65 1984-01-11     1
# 3  -121    63 1984-01-11     1
# 4  -120    63 1984-01-11     1
# 5  -121    65 1984-01-12     1
# 6  -120    65 1984-01-12     1
# 7  -121    63 1984-01-12     1
# 8  -120    63 1984-01-12     1
# 9  -121    65 1984-01-13     1
#10  -120    65 1984-01-13     1
# … with 140 more rows
```

Comment: Awesome, you are a life-saver here!

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
dt %>%
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Date) != 1)), .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(event = if (n() >= 5)
    cur_group_id()[n() >= 5]
    else    NA)
```

Comment: Thanks but No, it does not, it makes 150 groups (each row as a group) whereas I expect 35 groups based on the combination of x and y and grp.